# Expand the current range to include multiple non touching columns

Tags: arrays, regex, excel, vba, loops

How do I dynamically expand the current range to include multiple non touching columns?

I'm thinking there needs to be the inclusion of a dynamic multi-dimensional array set to complete this task.

```
Sub Convert Dates()

Dim Answer As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Last Row As Long

Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to run the macro",vbYesno,"Run the Program".)

If Answer = vbYes Then

    lastRow = Range ("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range ("Q2:@" & lastRow)

        If Instr(cell.value, ".") <> 0 Then
            Cell.value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
              "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})", "$3-$2-$1")
        End  if 

        If Instr (cell.value, "/") <> 0 Then
            cell.Value = RegexRepalce(Cell.Value,_
              "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})". "$3-$1=$2")
        End if  

        cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-d;@"

    Next
End if
End Sub

Function RegexReplace(ByVal text As String, _ 
                ByVal replace_what As String, _ 
                ByVal replace_with As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object 
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
    RE.Pattern = replace_what 
    RE.Global = True 
    RegexReplace = RE.Replace(text, replace_with)  
End Function
```

Comment: Function RegexReplace(ByVal text As String, _
ByVal replace_what As String, _
ByVal replace_with As String) As String

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = replace_what
RE.Global = True
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(text, replace_with)

End Function

Comment: Comment added below with function because website crashed on me.

Comment: Please do not put code in the comments.  Edit your original post to include it.

Comment: Do your cells contain dates (i.e. double precision numbers where, for instance, 42663.2395391204 represents 5:44:56am on 20 October 2016) or do they contain text (for instance "20/10/2016  05:44:56", or possibly just "20/10/2016")?

Comment: My cells are dates all in the same format. My only question is how to use the union method in this problem.

Comment: If your cells are dates, why do you need to use code to reformat them?   Just change the cell format to display them however you would like them displayed.

Comment: As far as your question re using `Union` goes, just replace your `Range` (I assume you are talking about the bit which says `Range ("Q2:@" & lastRow)`, although I hope the `@` is a typo) with your union, i.e. `Union(first range, second range)` (so perhaps `Union(Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow), Range("X2:X" & lastRow))`).  But I don't know what using a Union of, for instance, two fixed columns has to do with "dynamically expand the range of the current range to include multiple (non touching columns)".  You need to give more info in your question before we can help you with that "dynamic" part.

Comment: Just looking at your code - does it actually run for the single range?  In fact, does it even **compile**?  e.g. the space in the middle of a variable name in `Dim Last Row As Long`, `RegexReplace` v `RegexRepalce`, the extraneous period in `"Run the Program".`, the "@" in `Range ("Q2:@" & lastRow)`, the period instead of a comma in `"(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})". "$3-$1=$2"` (and should the "=" be "-"?)

Comment: The code compiles. The funky characters caused the code to error out in the edit box when typing and pasting the code. Therefore, I had to manually type it in. I noticed the typos.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats a nice complex way to do it. or you could just

Range(Range("A1"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).address